# Xpath1.0 local-name() versus namespace in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

For some reason, when I am using proper XPath without `local-name()`, I am not getting any value.

Non-working XPaths I have tried:

1. `//mon:ReturnUpdateRequest/urn:Header/urn:DocumentIdentifier/text()`
2. `soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/mon:ReturnUpdateRequest/urn:Header/urn:DocumentIdentifier/text()`

Both above expressions give the correct value in XPath tool and XMLspy.

Working XPath using `local-name()`:

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='DocumentIdentifier']
```

**Input request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mon="Monsanto:ServiceReturnUpdate" xmlns:urn="urn:monsanto:uscomm:service:header">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <mon:ReturnUpdateRequest Version="?">
            <urn:Header>
                <urn:DocumentIdentifier>1013083</urn:DocumentIdentifier>
                <urn:DocumentDateTime>2015-06-11T17:46:11.092-03:00</urn:DocumentDateTime>
                <urn:From>
                    <urn:PartnerName>1013083</urn:PartnerName>
                    <urn:PartnerIdentifier type="SAP_ID">1013083</urn:PartnerIdentifier>
                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                </urn:From>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <urn:To>
                    <urn:PartnerName>1013083</urn:PartnerName>
                    <urn:PartnerIdentifier type="SAP_ID">0001013083</urn:PartnerIdentifier>
                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                </urn:To>
                <urn:DataSource>APP</urn:DataSource>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <urn:SoftwareVersion>?</urn:SoftwareVersion>
            </urn:Header>
        </mon:ReturnUpdateRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mon="ServiceReturnDetail" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
                    <IIdent>
                        <!--    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='DocumentIdentifier']"/>-->
                        <xsl:value-of select="//mon:ReturnUpdateRequest/urn:Header/urn:DocumentIdentifier/text()"/>
                    </IIdent>
                    <ISrc>
                        <!--<xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='ReturnUpdateRequest']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='DocumentDateTime']"/>-->
                        <xsl:value-of select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/mon:ReturnUpdateRequest/urn:Header/urn:DocumentDateTime"/>
                    </ISrc>
                </urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where I am doing it wrong?

In your input XML, the `ReturnUpdateRequest` is in a namespace whose URI is `"Monsanto:ServiceReturnUpdate"`. You are trying to address it as `mon:ReturnUpdateRequest` - but your stylesheet binds the `mon` prefix to a completely different URI:

```
xmlns:mon="ServiceReturnDetail"
```

You have a similar problem with the `urn` prefix.

Here's a working example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:mon="Monsanto:ServiceReturnUpdate" 
xmlns:hdr="urn:monsanto:uscomm:service:header">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
                    <IIdent>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//mon:ReturnUpdateRequest/hdr:Header/hdr:DocumentIdentifier"/>
                    </IIdent>
                </urn:YSdsaUsseedRetUpdate>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: since you want to use the same `urn` prefix in the output but bind it to a different namespace, I have used a different prefix to address the input. What matters here is the URI, not the prefix itself.

Comment: My mistake about the typo. I missed when I was editing, however even after changes applied, it still doesn't give the value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :). But I have question if namespace was the problem than how come its works in onlne Xpath tool and XMLSpy?

Comment: I don't know. It should not work, and it doesn't work in any tool I have at my disposal..